# Can I create a new folder with a Visual Studio Item Template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vs-extensibility

I have successfully created (and manually edited) an Item Template that will add a number of files in one 'shot'. I want these files to all be created under a folder that should be created at the same time.

In Project Template .vstemplate files I can specify a Folder element, but the schema does not allow one in the Item Template.

Any know if this is possible or do I have to start looking at extending the IDE also?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured it out! You just need to edit the TargetFileName attribute of the ProjectItem element and suggest a fullpath...

```
<ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$\$fileinputname$.txt" ReplaceParameters="true">template.txt</ProjectItem>
```

In the above example if the user names the new item 'dog' VS will create a dog folder and copy the template.txt file as dog.txt into it.

Comment: Thanks for following up!